# In PowerShell, how do I copy the last alphabet characters from a string which also has numbers in it to create a variable?

Tags: powershell, alphanumeric

For example if the string is blahblah02baboon - I need to get the "baboon" seperated from the rest and the variable would countain only the characters "baboon". Every string i need to do this with has alphabet characters first then 2 numbers then more alphabet characters, so it should be the same process everytime.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read [ask] and post a [mcve]. Show us your code, what you tried, where it went wrong.

Comment: `$text = "blahblah02baboon"; 
 $from = $text.LastIndexOfAny("01234567890".ToCharArray()); 
 $lastWord = $text.Substring($from + 1); 
 Write-Host $lastWord;`

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to learn about regular expressions.

```
'blahblah02baboon' -replace '\D*\d*(\w*)', '$1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use regex

```
$MyString = "01baaab01blah02baboon"

# Match any character which is not a digit
$Result = [regex]::matches($MyString, "\D+")

# Take the last result
$LastResult = $Result[$Result.Count-1].Value

# Output
Write-Output "My last result = $LastResult"
```